# Like button css issue on website

Tags: css, facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

in the internal pages of my website, for example:

http://www.primapaginaonline.it/2014/06/27/gare-degli-sbandieratori-ritrovano-santemidio/

If i click the like button in the bottom at the page, in the colored box, the popup is cropped and I can't figure out why.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup field is cropped because the iframe css have a line that crops it to the 100% of the span.
embed, object, #content iframe{max-width:100%;} in the style.css 441-row